# Codeigniter not allowing the user to add duplicate emails to the db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to pull in the users table and if the email is already in the database, i don't want the user to be able to add another row with the same email. The below code is what I've put together so far but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Does anybody notice what I am doing wrong?

```
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
    $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
    $usersAddress = $this->input->post('usersAddress');
    $usersCity = $this->input->post('usersCity');
    $usersState = $this->input->post('usersState');
    $phoneNumber = $this->input->post('phoneNumber');

    $query1 = $this->db->get('users');
    foreach($query1->result() as $row) {    
        if ($row->email == $email) {
            echo 'Sorry but this email is already in use. Please go back and use a different email.';
        } else {
            $data = array('email' => $email,
                          'password' => $password,
                          'firstname' => $firstname,
                          'lastname' => $lastname,
                          'usersAddress' => $usersAddress,
                          'usersCity' => $usersCity,
                          'usersState' => $usersState,
                          'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber);
            $this->db->insert('users', $data); 
            $this->session->set_userdata('id', $this->db->insert_id());
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged', 'true');
            $this->session->set_userdata('firstname', $firstname);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lastname', $lastname);
            $this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
            mail($email,"KyPlays.org","You have successfully regstered at KyPlays.org");
            header("Location: ".base_url()."index.php/routers/startpage?requestedPageType=regPart2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't get all the users, check if the single email address is in the db or not.

Comment: So change the query or the foreach loop?

Comment: both, no need for the loop, check for the email, then do your if\else according to the the result

Comment: your code does add for each row a new entry if email not match. just think it over @Dogan +1

Comment: Okay I got it thanks for your all's help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the loop. Just check if the email is being used:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email));
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  // Show error message as email already exists in the database
} else {
  // Insert new user
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah I just got done rewriting it like how you have it written and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

you could also use the built in form_validation and use something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

see also:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html